# How serious is this spalling?

Tags: concrete, concrete-block

Spalling is occurring on the corner of the top of the first story. I'm curious as to how serious this is.

[image]

Comment: So, you think this was from water freeze cycles?  Looks like it could have been a high point on that corner that caused a pressure point that simply broke off the brick veneer.

Comment: What makes you say that it's spontaneous spalling? Looks like impact damage to me. Did it occur after you acquired the home? Please revise to provide more information.

Comment: According to Wikipedia:  **Spall are flakes of a material that are broken off a larger solid body and can be produced by a variety of mechanisms, including as a result of *projectile impact*, corrosion, weathering, cavitation, or excessive rolling pressure (as in a ball bearing). Spalling and spallation both describe the process of surface failure in which spall is shed**.  It appears the blocks are filled with concrete so i am guessing that it is not catastrophic failure.

Comment: I acquired the house a couple of years ago in pretty bad shape due to being uninhabited for some time. The siding and sheathing was T1-11 with pretty bad water damage on the corners, the foundation corner hadnt flaked off completely until after this winter (In northern california so all our precipitation is in winter). It could be that the corner is has become a high point due to settling in the deck around the house. Assuming it was due to the stress from being the high point how easy is this to address?